# GUI Calculator for Win10 and MacOS?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I want to make calculator with a GUI written in C# that can run on both MacOS and Windows10, can someone here advice me what project template to choose? I was thinking about using Xamarin, but I'm not 100% sure it would work.

Sorry for the stupid question, but I never worked with GUI's before, I always did simple console applications.

Comment: If it must run on both platforms, I would guess writing the code in “Java” may be a better approach. Java should run on both platforms using the same code.

Comment: Thanks for the input, John. I wanted to dig into C# since we will use the language in our next course on data science!

Comment: Well… then pick your poison on how you want to do this. I could be mistaken but I believe Xamarian is targeted towards phone applications. It is appearing you do not know “how” you want to do this. I can only suggest, you pick one and try it. The interfaces may differ; however, the underlying logic should be the same. Sounds like you need to try something first. Picking the environment is a good starting point. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xamarin.Forms. However, please note that Xamarin.Forms for Mac are in beta so setting it up is not automatic and there are couple of issues in it still: https://blog.xamarin.com/preview-bringing-macos-to-xamarin-forms/